# How to show a gradient diagonally in a view

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uikit, gradient

I am generating a `gradient` from 2 `UIColors` and then generating a `UIImage` out of it using these functions.

```
//Function to generate the UIImage from 2 colors.
func createGradient(color1: UIColor, color2: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
    let image = image(from: gradientLayer)
    return image
}

//Function to generate an Image from a CALayer.
func image(from layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, true, 0)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return outputImage ?? UIImage()
}
```

My result is this

[image]

But I would like to show this diagonally from the top left corner to the bottom right corner .... So the `Red` should start from the top left corner and fade into the `Yellow` as it goes down diagonally towards the bottom right corner.

I am not sure if should be generating the Gradient diagonally or if i should rotate the image after it is generated to show it diagonally.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the `startPoint` and `endPoint` to the gradient layer:

```
[...]
gradientLayer.startPoint = .init(x: 0, y: 0) // top left
gradientLayer.endPoint = .init(x: 1, y: 1) // bottom right
[...]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly .... Thanks.... Although i adjusted the `X` & `Y` values a little to make it exactly how i wanted it. But yes this was the solution.

Comment: Agree with @André Slotta. But the parameters should be adjusted to fit the question: gradientLayer.startPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)  , 
gradientLayer.endPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)

Comment: I don't get your comment, @YunCHEN. Shouldn't top left -> bottom right be `(0,0)` -> `(1,1)`?

Comment: @AndréSlotta, according to the screenshot, the gradientLayer's start position is x:0.5,y:0.0. Means it's from top-middle to bottom-middle.

Comment: Right, @YunCHEN. But the screenshot does not show what the author is trying to achieve. So I am not sure why someone voted your comment to be correct.

Comment: @AndréSlotta, ahh... you are right, according to the text, what the author wants is top-left to right-bottom. So let my comment be an additional suggestion for screenshot case.